# Can't find the path to proxy.pac file in OS X

Tags: macos

I need to control my proxy.pac file in OS X, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

I used

```
whereis proxy.pac
```

from terminal too — the whole story short: I want to find the path to a file in Mac OSX.

Comment: please cant anyone help

Comment: Has this been given to you as a URL? Your question is not very clear at all. What is the "something"?

Comment: @pjc50 lets say i want to learn the position of that file on my mac system. doing something with it is not such a big deal. i want to find the path to a file in mac, my issue is this

Comment: Why don't you ask for your *real* problem rather than your attempted solution? You can try to find files named `proxy.pac` with `sudo find / -iname "proxy.pac"` …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're asking the right question here.  By default, there is no file in OS X named proxy.pac.  Normally, a .pac (proxy auto-config) file is created by a network administrator and either a) installed on client computers (and if you'd done this, you'd hopefully know where you installed it); or b) loaded from a network server by the client.

If you have been given a .pac file (or a URL to load one from), you can configure OS X to use it in System Preferences -> Network preference pane -> select the active network service (interface) in the sidebar -> Advanced -> Proxies tab -> Automatic proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Spotlight to find the file, if even that doesn't work, try running `locate proxy.pac` from the Terminal. If that even doesn't work, try doing `sudo find / -name "*proxy.pac*"`.